# Pandas Query for date

Tags: python, pandas

I was looking through the pandas.query documentation but couldn't find anything specific about this.
Is it possible to perform a query on a date based on the closest date to the one given, instead of a specific date?

For example lets say we use the wine dataset and creates some random dates.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn import datasets
    dir(datasets)
    df = pd.DataFrame(datasets.load_wine().data)
    df.columns = datasets.load_wine().feature_names
    df.columns=df.columns.str.strip()
    
    
    
    
    def random_dates(start, end, n, unit='D'):
        ndays = (end - start).days + 1
        return pd.to_timedelta(np.random.rand(n) * ndays, unit=unit) + start
    
    
    
    np.random.seed(0)
    start = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01')
    end = pd.to_datetime('2022-01-01')
    datelist=random_dates(start, end, 178)

    df['Dates'] = datelist
```

if you perform a simple query on hue

```
df.query('hue == 0.6')
```

you'll receive three rows with three random dates. Is it possible to pick the query result that's closest to let's say 2017-1-1?

so something like

```
df.query('hue==0.6').query('Date ~2017-1-1')
```

I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a series, find the entries closest to a given date:

```py
def closest_to_date(series, date, n=5):
    date = pd.to_datetime(date)
    return abs(series - date).nsmallest(n)
```

Then we can use the index of the returned series to select further rows (or you change the api to suit you):

```
(df.loc[df.hue == 0.6]
 .loc[lambda df_: closest_to_date(df_.Dates, "2017-1-1", n=1).index]
)
```

Comment: This is cool. Would this be possible without using between? And could it account for a third query? Let's say Hue=0.6, alcohol  =13.7 and then the closest date?

Comment: Of course. The between was because my misreading, thought you wanted the *three* closest by date in my first reading. So I needed more by hue to make the filtering worthwhile. You can adapt the code to your liking, I think? I'll update the hue requirement.

Comment: Using `.loc[lambda]` is kind of an alternative to query style-wise. I wanted to show it off, but either way is fine, for hue, for example. But some things are just more flexible and possible using loc than using query.

Comment: Thanks!  I think I may just be writing it wrong. 
using: (df.loc[df.hue == 0.6 and df.alcohol== 13.17 ].loc[lambda df_: closest_to_date(df_.Dates, "2017-1-1", n=1).index])

I get a value error. But for one specific term your code works perfect

Comment: You'll need to use `&` for the "and" like this `df.loc[(df.hue == 0.6) & (df.alcohol == 13.17)]`  but that part is of course replaceable by `query` if you want

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the indeed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like:

```
df.query("('2018-01-01' < Dates) & (Dates < '2018-01-31')")

# Output
     alcohol  malic_acid  ...  proline                         Dates
6      14.39        1.87  ...   1290.0 2018-01-24 08:21:14.665824000
41     13.41        3.84  ...   1035.0 2018-01-22 22:15:56.547561600
51     13.83        1.65  ...   1265.0 2018-01-26 22:37:26.812156800
131    12.88        2.99  ...    530.0 2018-01-01 18:58:05.118441600
139    12.84        2.96  ...    590.0 2018-01-08 13:38:26.117376000
142    13.52        3.17  ...    520.0 2018-01-19 22:37:10.170825600

[6 rows x 14 columns]
```

Or using @variables:

```
date = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')
offset = pd.DateOffset(days=10)
start = date - offset
end = date + offset
df.query("Dates.between(@start, @end)")

# Output
     alcohol  malic_acid  ...  proline                         Dates
131    12.88        2.99  ...    530.0 2018-01-01 18:58:05.118441600
139    12.84        2.96  ...    590.0 2018-01-08 13:38:26.117376000
```

Comment: When first seeing the question I was also wondering " is there an interval or top closest?", but the question actually asks for *the* closest date, not any particular interval

Comment: Yes, I like this, but there are no betweens. The given dates are being read from a different dataframe, and there's only one given date per line.  The df example above(Wine data) would be equivalent to..... a database you're doing the lookup on based on some given data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have to use `query`, but this will give you the results you are looking for

```
df['Count'] = (df[df['hue'] == .6].sort_values(['Dates'], ascending=True)).groupby(['hue']).cumcount() + 1
df.loc[df['Count'] == 1]
```